# How to use setDragAndDrop() method?

Tags: java, android, methods, drag-and-drop

I am using android studio. While using startDrag() method it is showing deprecated. But startDragAndDrop() is showing correctly which is included in api 24 i think . Can anyone show a little example of using startDragAndDrop() method ?. could not find by google search though. In project min api is 15 and max is 24 .

Answer (score 0):

I guess google will publish a fix for this soon in the Support Lib, there should be a method to handle this issue like: ViewCompat.startDragAndDrop(...)

I created an issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=220912)